# project build succeeds on local machine but azure build fails

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, pipeline

I have a project that i have been building locally and publishing to Azure AppServices successfully for months.  I have allot of usage on the application now and I wanted to add a staging environment to my process.  To that end i have been trying to get Azure Piplines to work.  I configured a build and i am getting incompatible versions as per the picture below.  I have been struggling with this for a while:
[Azure Job Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5gMy.png)

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget restore` ?

Comment: Try `dotnet restore` or latest `nuget`, I made a test with this, but I fail to reproduce your issue, is there any demo project to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I will try that this morning

Comment: i updated nuget.exe to the latest 4.7.1 and now the project builds.  That was easy, but not intuitive.  Thanks for th help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought i would post the answer.  As per the comments by jayendran i updated nuget.exe to the latest version using the Nuget Installer command and the project started building.